# H2 db auto generate tables in spring 4

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2

are there some properties in spring 4 to autogenerate tables while using h2 db. Currently, I’m using the `EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder` and adding the scripts manually. However, is it possible to generate the tables like `SpringBoot`?

```
EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        EmbeddedDatabase db = builder
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL) //.H2 or .DERBY
            .addScript("db/sql/create-db.sql")
            .addScript("db/sql/insert-data.sql")
            .build();
        return db;
```

Comment: Just use hibernate `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` [property](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#configurations-hbmddl). See also `Schema generation` [chapter](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#schema-generation).

Comment: @SternK - does this work for spring mvc. I was assuming that it only works for springboot

Comment: It should work for any app that uses hibernate, because this is hibernate property.